# Keys.TAB does not work with Selenium HTMLUnitDriver

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

We are using HTMLUnitDriver in our project. We are using the latest 
version of Selenium 2.18.0. 
I'm trying to simulate TAB key press using Keys.TAB 
(org.openqa.selenium.Keys) to move the cursor from Username field to 
password field as follows:

```
objWebDriver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB); 
//Verify that focus is set to password text box. 
assertEquals(objWebDriver.findElement(By.id("password")), 
objWebDriver.switchTo().activeElement()); //Test fails here saying the 
focus is still on Username field
```

But, the same code works fine on FirefoxDriver.

If anybody has any idea on this or on simulating TAB key press using 
HTMLUnitDriver, please let me know.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I am having the same problem (specifically with function keys F1, F2 etc).

Comment: I've discovered the same problem, coming from a test that worked fine with the IE driver. Based on http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/keyboard-howto.html , I will hazard a guess that HTMLUnitDriver should be turning the TAB key into a call to HtmlPage.tabToNextElement(), rather than just sending the keycode. I changed my test to locate the next field and click() on it, rather than tabbing and it works with both drivers now.